# Can't Debug App on emulator

Tags: android-studio

I am using Android Studio 2.2.2 and ran the app on emulator Nexus_5_5_API_23
The app runs very well on emulator, but I can't debug it on emulator:

[image: image link]

Here is my console log:

> $ adb shell am start -n
>   "mmstart0312.com.webrtc_android/mmstart0312.com.webrtc_android.MainActivity"
>   -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D Waiting for application to come online:
>   mmstart0312.com.webrtc_android.test | mmstart0312.com.webrtc_android
>   Waiting for application to come online:
>   mmstart0312.com.webrtc_android.test | mmstart0312.com.webrtc_android
>   Waiting for application to come online:
>   mmstart0312.com.webrtc_android.test | mmstart0312.com.webrtc_android

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In Android-Studio : File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

May The Code Be With You!

Answer (score -1):

solved by attaching debugger to Android process once

Comment: Otherwise, please close the android studio and reopen the project.
Maybe works

Comment: Can you be more detailed please?